# Variable setup lines interfere with top level statements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I can't tell what's wrong with this script. I've tried putting all the variables in "void Start()" but nothing's worked. Please help.
From what I can tell, everything in the update script isn't the problem.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class MovementScript : MonoBehaviour{ }

{
    Rigidbody PlayerCube;
    float Jump = 1;
    float Speed = 1;
    void Update()
    {
        // All of this has the controls tilted 45 degrees. Deal with it for now.
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) ;
        { PlayerCube.AddForce(0, 0, Speed * 5); }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S)) ;
        { PlayerCube.AddForce(0, 0, Speed * -5); }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A)) ;
        { PlayerCube.AddForce(Speed * 5, 0, 0); }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D)) ;
        { PlayerCube.AddForce(Speed * -5, 0, 0); }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) ;
        { PlayerCube.AddForce(0, (float)(Jump * 2.5), 0); }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Remove the pair of parenthesis `{ }` after `MonoBehaviour`
- Remove semi-colon `;` after every `if` statement

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
public class MovementScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    Rigidbody PlayerCube;
    float Jump = 1;
    float Speed = 1;

    void Update()
    {
        // All of this has the controls tilted 45 degrees. Deal with it for now.
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W))
        { PlayerCube.AddForce(0, 0, Speed * 5); }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.S))
        { PlayerCube.AddForce(0, 0, Speed * -5); }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
        { PlayerCube.AddForce(Speed * 5, 0, 0); }

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.D))
        { PlayerCube.AddForce(Speed * -5, 0, 0); }

        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        { PlayerCube.AddForce(0, (float)(Jump * 2.5), 0); }
    }
}
```

---

Modify your `Update()` method for simplicity

```cs
void Update()
{
    PlayerCube.AddForce(-Speed * 5 * Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical"), 0, Speed * 5 * Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal"));

    if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
    {
        PlayerCube.AddForce(0, (float)(Jump * 2.5), 0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.W)) ;
```

You are ending your `if` condition with the semi-colon at the end of this line.  You need to remove it.  E.g. -

```
if (1 != 1) ;
{ Console.WriteLine("???"); }
```

will print `???` to the console, because I terminated the if statement before moving to the next statement.